# Stata - searching if a particular part of a set of characters has a specific character

Tags: stata

How do I this in Stata?

Say my data are:

```
Var1
Whoareyou
Whoisme
Idontknow
Isthatyou
Isyoume
```

How do I know if the 6th and 7th characters are "me"?

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is correct only by accident.

```
substr(var1, 6, 2) == "me"
```

The last argument of `substr()` is the maximum length of the substring extracted, not the position of the last character selected.

In the examples given `me` occurs at the end of the string, so using `6, 7` will work in those cases.